# Do SAS formats transfer to Rstudio?

Tags: r, sas, format, r-haven

I have a dataset that I have transferred from SAS to Rstudio via the `haven` package.
But when I inspect my dataset in R, I can see that some of the formatted variables are indeed still formatted, while some of the variables are shown as the 'raw' variables without the format.

For instance, I have a numeric variable, `M3_SCORE` and then right next to it, the formatted version, `M3_LEVELS` (in SAS, this would be formatted to now be a categorical variable).
In the dataset in Rstudio, however, I can only see the raw numbers and not the new categories.

When I use `str(dataset)` to inspect the variables, it says that both `M3_SCORE` and `M3_LEVELS` are numeric, but under `M3_LEVELS` it says

```
..-attr(*, "format.sas")=chr "FMTM3SCORE"
```

Does this mean that Rstudio will still process `M3_LEVELS` as a categorical variable, even though I can't see it?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe this attribute is only there to preserve the information from reading the file. If you want it to be treated as a categorical variable you'll have to cast it as such using `factor` function.

Comment: I think user defined formats are not transferred but standard formats may be.